# CURL as private member of C++ class

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

My goal is to build a C++ class to abstract away several POST methods.  I reckon I want to have one instance of a CURL object for the entire class, which all the methods share.

**Here's my test setup which works fine**

Header file

```
#pragma once
#include <curl/curl.h>
class RPC
{
public:
    RPC();
};
```

cpp file

```
RPC::RPC()
{
    CURL* m_curl;
    m_curl = curl_easy_init();
    // curl_easy_setopt() and curl_easy_perform()
    curl_easy_cleanup(m_curl);
}
```

This code builds and runs and produces the expected output.  The problem is when I try to make `m_curl` a private member of the `RPC` class.  The `RPC` class will have multiple methods calling `curl_easy_perform()`, and I do not want to have to call `curl_easy_init()` and `curl_easy_cleanup` every time.  I want to call them once in the constructor and destructor, respectively.

**This is what I want**

Header file

```
#pragma once
#include <curl/curl.h>
class RPC
{
public:
    RPC();
    ~RPC();
    void someMethod();
private:
    CURL* m_curl;
};
```

cpp file

```
RPC::RPC()
{
    m_curl = curl_easy_init();
}
RPC::~RPC()
{
    curl_easy_cleanup(m_curl);
}
void RPC::someMethod()
{
    // curl_easy_setopt() and curl_easy_perform()
}
```

The problem is with this line in the header file:

`CURL* m_curl;`

I get the following 3 build errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

I have also tried calling curl_easy_init() in an initializer list, like this:

```
RPC::RPC() : m_curl(curl_easy_init())
```

But that produces the same build errors.

Any help is appreciated! :)

edit: I did include curl in the header.

Comment: Have your tried #include <curl/curl.h> in the header file?

Comment: Oops, should have included that in the example code.
I do have curl included in the header file:

`#pragma once`
`#include <curl/curl.h>`

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the same file you have posted? Be sure the file is not modified in the editor and is written on the disk.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I am compiling that code.

Answer (score 1):

in the first case you can have CURL include only in the cpp file but for the second case you have to include CURL in the header file.

Comment: curl is included in the header file, I have edited my question to show that

Answer (score 0):

Your header needs to look something like this:

```
#ifndef RPC_H
#define RPC_H

#include "curl/curl.h"

class RPC
{
public:
    RPC();
    ~RPC();
    void someMethod();
private:
    CURL* m_curl;
};

#endif
```

In other words:

- You need a declaration for [CURL](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl.html).
- You do this by #include "curl/curl.h" in your header.
- Your header also needs an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), if you don't already have one.

Comment: curl is included in the header file, I have edited my question to show that

Comment: And you're using "#pragma once", too.  Cool :)  Q: Are you still getting the same compile error(s)?  Q: Which line(s)?  Per your post, I *ASSUME* all three errors were from line 10 in the header: `CURL* m_curl`.  But "Assuming" is "Bad".  Please CONFIRM the line number, and SHOW the corresponding source code.  Q: Is it possible you have some weird "#define"  somewhere that might be "overriding" the default definition of "CURL"?  The line 10 you showed us *SHOULD* compile with error :(

Comment: You are correct, all 3 errors come from the line:

`CURL* m_curl;`

The code is exactly as shown, save for the `// curl_easy_setopt() and curl_easy_perform()` which has some actual curl options set and what not.

I also would have expected that to compile just fine.  As of right now I have resorted to making a curlWrapper() method which handles the `m_curl = curl_easy_init();` and `curl_easy_cleanup(m_curl);` parts, but that will execute every time I use curl.  Oh well...

Comment: Q: What do you want to bet that the error is caused by one of the lines PRECEDING "private: CURL* m_curl", in something you're not showing us?